# Do all enemies have Viral forms?

Tags: hyperdimension-neptunia-mk2

I've noticed some enemies (and some "types" of enemies, like the pacman ghosts) will fairly often suffer a viral infection and turn nasty. I've also noticed the opposite; many enemy types, especially big ones, seem to never go under an infection.

Are there "infected" versions of all the monsters or just some of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; certain enemies ('Vaders and Pacman ghosts as examples) always have a viral form and other enemy types (for instance all "dangerous" enemies like Dolphins and Dragons) never have viral forms. You'll eventually get a hang of which types may turn viral and which never will.